# GWT - No answer from CallBack from REST Service

Tags: json, gwt, rest, asynchronous

I have my REST service : http://localhost:4242/myrestservice/getobject
which returns some JSON data

Then, i have my GWT client :
http://localhost:4242/gwtclient
that client is supposed to do Async calls to the REST service.

Im pretty new to this, so my first idea was to do the following :

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode("http://localhost:4242/myrestservice/getobject"));
builder.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
builder.setCallback(new MyObjectDescCallback());    
builder.setRequestData("");
Request req  = builder.send();

...

final class MyObjectDescCallback implements RequestCallback {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                showAlert("error = "+exception.getMessage());

                GWT.log(exception.getMessage());
       }
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
showAlert("response = " + response.getStatusCode());
//Do my stuff here
}
}
}
```

Unfortunately,i get no response.

I checked on the Rest service, and it does send the object

It seems that my GWT app doesnt receive the answer.

Any idea how to make it work ?

UPDATE

Here are my results with Firebug :

```
Response Headers
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type    application/json
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Sun, 24 Apr 2011 11:04:15 GMT

Request Headers
Host    127.0.0.1:4242
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0
Accept  application/json
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://localhost:4242/gwtclient/gwtclient.html
Origin  http://localhost:4242
```

But i get response.getStatusCode() = 0
and empty response !

UPDATE 2 :

I feel so dumb now...

The issue was in fact SOP ...

I was using the URL localhost, but in my code i was using 127.0.0.1 !

Damn....

Comment: I have read about SOP, but since they are both on Localhost with same port, i believe it shouldnt be an issue in my case : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy   unless i understood wrong?

Comment: Did you use Firebug? You can check if your GWT client makes the call or not in the net panel. You can also see the answer that your rest service returns.

Comment: i updated my post with Firebug logs ... the answer is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to use a Async callback but you never use `new AsyncCallback<string>()` in your code. This is how I make async calls to a server with my gwt application: (I don't use JSON but that doesn't really matter here I think)

```
request object = new request();
object.getMessageXml("test.php", "GET", null, new AsyncCallback<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        //error handling
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        // do some stuff with the result
    }
});
```

And this is the request class:

```
public void getMessageXml(String file, String type, String requestData, final AsyncCallback<String> callback) {

        RootLayoutPanel.get().addStyleName("loading");

        final String url = "test/" + file;
        RequestBuilder rb;

        try {
            if(type == "POST") {
                rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, URL.encode(url));
            }
            else {
                rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));
            }

            rb.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-javascript; charset:ISO-8859-1");
            rb.sendRequest(requestData, new RequestCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {

                    if(Response.SC_OK == response.getStatusCode()) {

                        callback.onSuccess(response.getText()); 
                    }
                    else {
                        //error 
                    }
                    RootLayoutPanel.get().removeStyleName("loading");   
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) { 
                    callback.onFailure(exception);
                }   
            }); 
        }
        catch(RequestException rex) {
            callback.onFailure(rex);
        }   
    }
```

[EDIT:]
Maybe you find something [here:](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/JSON.html)

Comment: i did those changes as well, but i still get response.getStatusCode() = 0

Comment: I've post a link in my answer with some information about gwt and json. Maybe you are something with it?

Comment: Its really frustrating because i followed this link already before. Using Firebug i can see the response is received, it  even shows me the correct length. Except the Resonse is empty.

Comment: As i said above, the issue was SOP ... i was using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in my code .

Comment: hey @guigui42 can u please tell me which link you followed to implement the above thing. I have the same situation but I cant find the solution for it.